# Eclipse, jetty и автоматическая перезагрузка страниц

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Шаг 1: Написать "Hello World!" — приложение можно запустить и оно выводит в лог - "Hello World!".

Шаг 2: Написать "Hello Server!" — приложение запускает jetty server (на localhost:8080). В браузере можно открыть страничку localhost:8080 и увидеть строку "Hello Server!".

Шаг 3: Изменить страницу, которую возвращает сервер так, чтобы она перегружала себя раз в секунду. Вынести создание страницы в отдельный класс (PageGenerator).

Первые два шага разобрался, как делать, а с третьим вообще непонятно. Подскажите что почитать по теме, хочется понять, как такое делать.

Проблема в том, что я даже не знаю, что мне нужно гуглить. Как я понял, требуется использование servlet api для ежесекундного перезапуска страницы. Я не прошу готовое решение, а хотя бы то, что что требуется для этого использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гуглить можно, например, так "java servlet auto reload page".

Есть 3 способа:

1. Установить заголовок "Refresh" `response.setIntHeader("Refresh",1);`.
2. Установить метатег на странице  `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />`.
3. С помошью javascript функций `setTimeout` и `location.reload`.